# Unable to create Model without fields in Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a model in Django rest framework, without any field information as I'm using MongoDB which doesn't have any fixed fields

twitterdashmodel.py-----

```
class TwitterMaster(models.Model):
```

I need a way out so that I can use model to make query functionality from function based views. I am novice to Django rest framework. Need a guidance/solution to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You usually write [**`pass`** [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/pass.html) to end a scope without any statements:

```
class TwitterMaster(models.Model):
    pass

# … something else …
```

Note that Django will however add a field itself: an `AutoField` with the name `id` that is the primary key of the model. For more information, see the [*automatic primary key fields* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm getting blank response  when trying to make query from view and using the following serializer.  class TwitterdashappSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
 class Meta:
  model = TwitterMaster
  fields = '__all__'

Comment: @SCM: what view(set) do you use here? What if you set `fields = ['id']`?

Comment: Its modelViewset => class TwitterdashappViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
 #queryset = TwitterMaster.objects.all()
 permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
 serializer_class = TwitterdashappSerializer 

 def get_queryset(self):
  queryset = TwitterMaster.objects.all() 
  tt = self.request.query_params.get('tt')  
  if tt:
   condition = Q(tweet_text__contains=tt)&Q(tweet_favorite_count=13)
   queryset = queryset.filter(condition)
  #print( str(queryset.query))
  return queryset

Comment: @SCM: can you please ask a new question, or edit this one. By not indenting it correctly, it is quite hard to read.

Comment: I have created another question related to it . Blank model can be created by your way and also by  defining document comment as mentioned by Narendra Kumawat, but I'm not getting any key response.  Can you please guide me on this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58452929/how-to-get-record-using-blank-model-and-not-creating-any-serializer-class-in-dja

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Python Doc String](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-docstrings/)

```
class TwitterMaster(models.Model):
    """TwitterMaster do ...."""
```